Not to setup solana rpc node. -2.8 Slots Behind
A little guidance to trobuleshoot this issue would be appreciated. Thanks in advance
Server Specs:
CPU: AMD EPYC 7402P 24-Core Processor
RAM: DDR4 2666MHz 512GB (4 x 128GB 2666MHz RDIMM)
Bandwitdth: 1GBPS

can you provide some more information

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
